# How could I send a text?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, mobile

I am currently working on an app for Windows Phone. What I wish to do is simple - allow the user to set a time, and, at this time, the phone will send a text message to a specified number.

Is it possible to do this ? How can I do this ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: You could set a background agent for the time; anyway you won't be able to send message without user confirmation. This is MS policy for Windows Phone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to launch the Messaging application with the "Body" and "To" field programmatically field in.
The [SmsComposeTask Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.smscomposetask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is what you need to launch the messaging application.